# What was Origin about, when it was the religion of the Ori only, i.e. as they were still on the mortal plane?

Tags: stargate-sg1, religion

Origin seems like a fundamentalist religion from the get-go, given the conflict between the Ori and the Ancients.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, this is never really addressed in the show directly. I think we can, with just some minor guessing, to answer it.

Facts, as per [SGCommand](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Alteran_division):

1. Alterans were the first iteration of human evolution.
2. In their Home Galaxy they determined that their evolution will eventually take them on a path where they will no longer exist as a physical life.
3. This caused the division between their ranks.
4. Conflict broke out between the factions: religious Ori and secular Alterans.
5. To avoid genocide and/or forced conversion to the truth - as both were against their convictions - Alterans packed and left

Guessing:

1. They disagreed on what the Ascension means for them and their society. Ori believed this is the sign of their exceptionalism as a form of life, other Alterans thought this to be a natural path for all living sentients.
2. This point of view drove the Ori to eventually adopt extreme beliefs, that tolerated no dissent.

Supporting evidence (of which most is [here](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/The_Fourth_Horseman,_Part_1)):

1. Both ascended factions - though by now Alterans are the Ancients - and Ori stick to their beliefs, though Ori follow the letter of the Ascension rules, constantly bouncing off the extreme technicality of it, but still giving Ancients no excuse to intervene
2. Ancients are big on freedom of choice, while Ori are big on domination.
3. Both factions either died of diseases or ascended, re-seeding their galaxies with  another iteration of humans, treating them accordingly to the respective faction beliefs, except for the Ancients to shield inhabitants of other galaxies from Ori

This means there is little connection between first Ori beliefs and the religion of The Origin. The former is just excuse to treat life on lower planes of existing as source of power by the forcing the latter on that "primitive life".

Comment: This is better, I think I misread the question.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Don't worry, You weren't the only one to not see the question in the title...

Answer (score 2):

Not quite from the start, [but (50+) millions of years](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Ancient#History):

> Hundreds of millions of years ago, the Alterans, the first evolution
> of humanity in four galaxies, lived together as one society on an
> evolutionary path to Ascension in the Alteran Home Galaxy. A split
> then occurred among the Alterans, dividing them into two factions: the
> Ancients (who still called themselves the Alterans), who were more
> secular and science-oriented, and the Ori, who became more religious.
>
> Eventually, the Ori became so extreme in their beliefs that they tried
> to wipe out the Ancients. The Ancients' numbers were too few, and they
> were ultimately forced to hide their ways. Though they considered
> using their knowledge to defend themselves, they faced a war of
> attrition, one they ultimately believed that they could not win. To
> avoid genocide, the Ancients built a ship and left their galaxy, while
> the Ori remained. They both eventually ascended, but their paths
> continued to differ.

That the split occurred before finding Earth, and Earth was only found by them 50 or more million years ago:

> 50+ million years ago the Ancients discovered the Milky Way, and first
> colonized the planets Dakara and Terra, which would later be known as
> Earth.

Indications are that it was the Alterans who were the Ancients, not the Ori who formed an alliance with the other three great races, Asgard, Nox and Furlings at that time.